# How to optimize mySQL query with indexes when column contains duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve all messages from a table whose latitude and longitude values fall within a certain n meter radius.

```
$messages = DB::table('messages')->select('*')
                                 ->whereBetween( 'latitude', array($userLatitudeFloor, $userLatitudeCeil) ) 
                                 ->whereBetween( 'longitude', array($userLongitudeCeil, $userLongitudeFloor) )
                                 ->where('message_permission', 'public')
                                 ->orderBy('timestamp', 'DESC')
                                 ->take(100)
                                 ->get();
```

In attempting to optimize the query time, I tried to utilize a Primary Key index on the latitude column.  However it appears that mySQL does not allow indexes to be created when the column contains duplicate values e.g.

[image]

My question is there a way to use indexes when the column contains duplicate values or does mySQL offer an alternative method.

Indexing might be the wrong route to take here in order to mitigate the search query time.  If so, any suggestions for alternative methods are more than welcome.  Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide sql create statement to all tables and sql query to select values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `KEY`, not a `PRIMARY KEY`. By definition, the primary key is a unique identifier for the row, but an ordinary index does not have a problem with duplicates.